# Retrieving concatenated field value in solr

Tags: solr, fuzzy-search, query-parser

Enviornment ==> solr - solr-8.9.0, java version "11.0.12" 2021-07-20 LTS

Following .csv file is indexed in solr

```
id,cat,name,price,inStock,author,series_t,sequence_i,genre_s
0553573403,book,Game Thrones Clash,7.99,true,George R.R. Martin,"A Song of Ice and Fire",1,fantasy
0553573404,book,Game ,7.99,true,George R.R. Martin,"A Song of Ice and Fire",1,fantasy
0553573405,book,Game Kings Storm,7.99,true,George R.R. Martin,"A Song of Ice and Fire",1,fantasy
0553573406,book,Games Clash,7.99,true,George R.R. Martin,"A Song of Ice and Fire",1,fantasy
0553573407,book,Game Thronesa,7.99,true,George R.R. Martin,"A Song of Ice and Fire",1,fantasy
0553573408,book,Game Thrones Clash,7.99,true,George R.R. Martin,"A Song of Ice and Fire",1,fantasy
0553573409,book,GameThrones Clash,7.99,true,George R.R. Martin,"A Song of Ice and Fire",1,fantasy
0553573410,book,Game ThronesClash,7.99,true,George R.R. Martin,"A Song of Ice and Fire",1,fantasy
```

field-type : text_general is configured for field :'name'.

Query shall run over input field 'name' having the value 'Game Thrones Clash'.
What I need to do is somehow

1. if there is a minimum of 75% of tokens are fuzzy matches then it should result in output. Output will be having id as '0553573403', '0553573406', '0553573407', '0553573408'.
2. If 'name' values are concatenated then it should also result in output. The output will be having id as '0553573409'(GameThrones Clash), '0553573410'(Game ThronesClash).

I understand that Extended DisMax includes query parameters 'mm'(Minimum should match) with fuzzy search functionality.
Following query is satisfying the criteria 1 :

```
curl -G http://$solrIp:8983/solr/testCore2/select --data-urlencode "q=(name:'Game~' OR name:'Thrones~' OR name:'Clash~')" --data-urlencode "defType=edismax" --data-urlencode "mm=75%" --data-urlencode "sort=id asc"
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":2,
    "params":{
      "mm":"75%",
      "q":"(name:'Game~' OR name:'Thrones~' OR name:'Clash~')",
      "defType":"edismax",
      "sort":"id asc"}},
  "response":{"numFound":4,"start":0,"numFoundExact":true,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"0553573403",
        "cat":["book"],
        "name":["Game Thrones Clash"],
        "price":[7.99],
        "inStock":[true],
        "author":["George R.R. Martin"],
        "series_t":"A Song of Ice and Fire",
        "sequence_i":1,
        "genre_s":"fantasy",
        "_version_":1738145066191421440},
      {
        "id":"0553573406",
        "cat":["book"],
        "name":["Games Clash"],
        "price":[7.99],
        "inStock":[true],
        "author":["George R.R. Martin"],
        "series_t":"A Song of Ice and Fire",
        "sequence_i":1,
        "genre_s":"fantasy",
        "_version_":1738145066196664320},
      {
        "id":"0553573407",
        "cat":["book"],
        "name":["Game Thronesa"],
        "price":[7.99],
        "inStock":[true],
        "author":["George R.R. Martin"],
        "series_t":"A Song of Ice and Fire",
        "sequence_i":1,
        "genre_s":"fantasy",
        "_version_":1738145066196664321},
      {
        "id":"0553573408",
        "cat":["book"],
        "name":["Game Thrones Clash"],
        "price":[7.99],
        "inStock":[true],
        "author":["George R.R. Martin"],
        "series_t":"A Song of Ice and Fire",
        "sequence_i":1,
        "genre_s":"fantasy",
        "_version_":1738145066197712896}]
  }}
```

but following documents are not part of the output.

```
0553573409,book,GameThrones Clash,7.99,true,George R.R. Martin,"A Song of Ice and Fire",1,fantasy
0553573410,book,Game ThronesClash,7.99,true,George R.R. Martin,"A Song of Ice and Fire",1,fantasy
```

What to change in the query to result above documents?

For Field 'Name', multivalued will be false.

Note - A change in case within a word: "CamelCase" is not neccessay. It may be 'Gamethrones Clash', 'Game Thronesclash'

I also indexed data with 'ShingleFilterFactory' for fieldType : text_general.

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

But not able to understand what to change in query to retrieve all following results for input value ('Game Thrones Clash') with a minimum of two token fuzzy-matched.

1. '0553573403', '0553573406', '0553573407', '0553573408'
2. '0553573409'(GameThrones Clash), '0553573410'(Game ThronesClash).

Comment: [ bracket shoes that your field is defined as multivalued...not sure if it is needed in your case...you can make it false and second thing is it seems you have the field as non-tokenised so apply text field with tokenizer and filters to it

Comment: if the name is concanated it wont be able to bring the values unless you index the data with that aspect...you can use the edgegramtokenizer to achieve that but its may create the huge index for you if you have large data...

Comment: The WordDelimiter filter will expand `GameThrones` and `ThronesClash` into two separate tokens by default: https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/indexing-guide/filters.html#word-delimiter-graph-filter - that should solve issue #2. Another option is to use a ShingleFilter to combine two tokens to one when querying (i.e. `Game Thrones` gets combined into `GameThrones` as well), but that won't play nicely with your fuzzy query.